# Which hook will load after node page load and file download

Tags: nodes, files

I need to run  `db_insert` and `db_update` once after a node is loaded. Its only for particular node content type. Which hook can i use for it?. Can i add that hook in template.php instead of adding it in a `.module` file?.

I need another hook which will run once after a file gets downloaded.

Comment: `db_merge` is worth looking. Merge query is a combination of an Insert query and an Update query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you need re node hooks, since your title says "after node page load" and the body of your question says "after a node is loaded". Those are very much two different things. If you're looking for a hook that fires after the page has been displayed on the front end, there isn't one (though you could theoretically implement your own using AJAX).

Your best bet would be to consult the list of [Node API Hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7) and select the one that best suits your exact use case.

To get notified of file downloads through the private file system you can implement [hook_file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7). There's nothing similar for public file downloads, as Drupal's default behaviour is to pass straight through to existing files, without bootstrapping (hence no hook could ever be fired).

Comment: Thanks Clive. My requirement is to store the node ID and timestamps(when the node viewed) to database once after the node opened to the user. Same for download also.

Comment: hook_node_view() would probably make most sense for that. If you want to make absolutely, positively sure that the page has been viewed (i.e. it didn't throw an error before it was fully built and delivered to the user), you'd need to implement an AJAX call front the front end (would only catch users with JS enabled obviously). If you trust your web server, you could register a PHP shutdown function to do it instead. In fact there are quite a lot of different ways to do that :) hook_node_view() should be fine for 90% of use cases IMO